# Symfony 2 : How to concatenate multiple fields into one in a form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have searched through the internet to find a way to concatenate multiple fields into one for user input, and then break down before updating database.

I work on a project where a doctrine entity have these fields :

```
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $disponibilite;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $integrite;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $confidentialite;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $preuve;
```

Each of these integers should be between 1 and 5.
Actually the form looks like this :
[4 fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mrzs.png)

I want something like this :
[1 field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMzlJ.png)

I noticed that Symfony offered a tool that would solve my problem: data converters. But I do not see how they can afford to insert 4 values in the database from a single field.

Do you know another way to customize the form?

Comment: I would simply go for a text field mapped to a fake property and just use the setProperty to divide your string and set the right properties and the getProperty to concatenate the 4 properties into one string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could add a new property to your class e.g

```
private $singleField

/* a getter that builds up the unified value */    
public function getSingleField(){
  return $this->disponibilite.$this->integrite.$this->confidentialite.$this->preuve
} 


/* a setter that sets the properties by unified value */
public function setSingleField($value){

 $arr=str_split((string)$value);
 if(is_array($arr) && count($arr) == 3){

    $this->disponibilite = $arr[0];
    $this->integrite = $arr[1];
    ...

 }else{
   return false
 }

}
```

and in your formbuilder you only add the property "singleField"

Comment: How can I validate the data ? I validate in YAML, but Symfony don't recognize the singleField property.

Comment: you can validate in your setSingleField function, the validation for all properties e.g disponsibilitie will still work as you set them, so if any of your properties is not valid it will fail on flush